# How to add in non-tabbed login page for new Ionic "tabs" app?

Tags: html, ios, css, ionic-framework

Just starting Ionic, I used the following command with the IOS simulator:

```
ionic start myApp tabs
```

All of this is working fine, but now I want to have a login page (no tabs down the bottom, no header on the top), and after the user logs in here, they can then access the tabs.

I'm currently having trouble implementing this login page. This is what I've got:

```
$stateProvider.state('login', {
  url: '/login',
  views: {
    'login': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
      controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    }
  }
}).state('tab', {
  url: '/tab',
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
}).state('tab.dash', {
  url: '/dash',
  views: {
    'tab-dash': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
      controller: 'DashCtrl'
    }
  }
}).state('tab.chats', {
  url: '/chats',
  views: {
    'tab-chats': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-chats.html',
      controller: 'ChatsCtrl'
    }
  }
}).state('tab.chat-detail', {
  url: '/chats/:chatId',
  views: {
    'tab-chats': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/chat-detail.html',
      controller: 'ChatDetailCtrl'
    }
  }
}).state('tab.account', {
  url: '/account',
  views: {
    'tab-account': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-account.html',
      controller: 'AccountCtrl'
    }
  }
});
```

Notice the first part - `.state('login'`, but for some reason, that will not work with the following line of code:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
```

It works for any other URL I try (e.g. `/tabs/dash`), but I can't seem to get `/login` working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set routing for login page as following:

```
.state('login', {
  url: '/login',
  templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
  controller: 'LoginCtrl'
})
```

[Here](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/CbBsA) is the codepen example.